# Offer "last 7 days" view for flag history

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flag-history, user-experience, flag-ban

**TL;DR** Please put some visuals into the flag history view to show what exactly is meant by "the last seven days".

I was briefly getting the ["please review"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405) notice when I flagged something, and went to investigate my latest flags.

(To keep this self-contained, the linked answer explains that you can get a "please review" if you have at least ten flags in the last seven days, and at least 10% of those are declined.  There's another, stronger threshold at 25%.)

Unfortunately, the [flag history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/874188) view does not make it very easy to see which flags are from the last seven days; so it's hard to figure out which ones to review.

(In fact, with time zone differences, uncertainties about when the automation examines my flag history, and the plethora of tangentially related questions to wade through if you want to look for actual documentation, I would say it is humanly impossible for a regular user to figure this out.)

My humble suggestion would be to put a divider below, or perhaps a different background color behind, the entries which are the current "last seven days"; but I'm sure the gifted UX experts out there can come up with a better spec for how exactly to solve this conundrum.

Comment: For background, I posted a now-deleted [previous question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307093/getting-please-review-although-most-flags-okay?noredirect=1#comment252740_307093) (requires 10k to view) which was resolved with the help of [a moderator](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) (thanks!)

Comment: What the feature tries to say: *you are doing it wrong*.  What you are asking for it to say: *I like to continue doing it wrong, just tell me when to slow down a bit so I won't get blocked*.   I wonder how long that [status-declined] will take :)

Comment: @HansPassant How so?  It asks me to review the declined flags; I would like to, but it seems awfully hard.  We should fix that.

Comment: Also, for context, how is 1,203 "helpful" flags "doing it wrong"?  I'll agree that 13 declined comment flags is a higher number than I'd like it to be, but those are not the topic here (none of them in the last 7 days AFAICT), and 13/185 all time is well below the threshold.

Comment: I'm just going to leave this here....I'm in the process of looking at overhauling the flag history page to make things a bit easier to find declines, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was actually implemented (by Oded, I think) years ago.

However, as of today, [we link directly to the filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288009/add-a-link-to-the-relevant-meta-post-in-the-flag-ban-notice/323066#323066) from the "please review" messages, so now it's *extra*-completed.